# How to create a new object in the sub and assign it to one of argument?

Tags: excel, class, vba

I have following code in vba, excel. First, I created class 'List':

```
Public next as List
Public val as Integer
```

and next I want to do sth like this

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ls as List
    Set ls = new List

     Set_val ls.next, 8
     Debug.Print (ls.next is Nothing) 'True - why?
     Debug.Print ls.next.val 'Error
end sub


Sub Set_val(l as List, v as Integer)
     Set l = new List
     l.val = v
end sub
```

But it's not working and I get error message "object or variable with block variable not set". Do you know how it should be done properly?

Comment: `Set` is probably not the best choice for a Sub name...

Comment: Is this VB.NET or VBA? And, as mentioned, don't use Set as a Sub-name. I wouldn't use 'next' or 'val' as variable names either - it creates very confusing, and error-prone, code.

Comment: It's VBA, excel, I know there are not proper names for variables and functions, but this is only example that I created to show the issue.

Comment: You haven't told us what line creates the error. It might be this one `Set_val ls.next, 8`. Does your List constructor create a new (next) instance of List?

Comment: 'Debug.Print ls.next.val' this line creates error. It looks like the ls.next has not been created at all. The statment (ls.next is nothing) return True.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ls as List
    Set ls = new List

     Set ls.Next = Set_val(8)
     Debug.Print (ls.next is Nothing) 'True - why?
     Debug.Print ls.next.val 'Error
end sub

Function Set_val(v as Integer) as List
    Set Set_val = new List
    Set_val.val = v
end sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working, but do you know why my solution is not? Is there any other way to do it but instead of function use sub?

Comment: @user2602548: Yes. Your solution is not working because VBA doesn't work that way; it works the way I show above. Use the language and it's idioms, rather than trying to fore it into something else.

Comment: @user2602548: BTW: The best thank you is an acceptance and/or an up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

The `Public next As List` can't work, because `Next` cannot be used.

You never change the value of `next`. The function changes the value of `val` instead.

I don't understand what you are trying to do, but this should help:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ls As List
    Set ls = New List

     Set_val ls, 8
     Debug.Print (ls.next0 Is Nothing) 'True - why?
     Debug.Print ls.next0.val 'Error
End Sub

Sub Set_val(l As List, v As Integer)
     Set l.next0 = New List
     l.val = v
End Sub
```